# How to write xpath for the calendar element tied within td with class and aria-label

Tags: selenium-webdriver, xpath

I am trying to write the XPath for the below element but I am not able to locate it

```
<td class="_1dmyat7f" role="button" aria-disabled="false" aria-label="Selected start date. Saturday, 31 August 2019" tabindex="0" style="width: 33px; height: 32px;">31</td>
```

I am trying like

```
//td[@class="_1dmyat7f"] //aria-label[contains(text(),"31"]
```

Comment: help me in how to handle this element and write the xpath

Comment: Can you cross the HTML, seems an invalid HTML snippet, incomplete start_tag and no end_tag for td...

Comment: You should spend some time reading some basic XPath tutorials. The XPath you are using isn't formatted correctly. What error are you getting with the current XPath?

Answer (score 2):

I would just go about it by looking for the td that contains some of the text on the aria-label attribute.   For example...

```
//td[contains(@aria-label, "Selected start date")]
```

or being more specific

```
//td[@class="_1dmyat7f"][contains(@aria-label, "Selected start date")]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
//td[@class='1dmyat7f' and contains(@aria-label,'31')]
```

Or:

```
//td[@class='1dmyat7f' and contains(text(),'31')]
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.